# How to send a facebook notification to a user using curl without facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, curl

I tried the following with the following output from Facebook since this requires a post.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/appUserId/notifications?access_token=*****&href=index.php&template=test');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
var_dump(json_decode($response));
```

Then from this i get the following, What might i be doing wrong?

```
string '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="facebook">
  <head>
    <title>Facebook | Error</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta name="robots"              content="noindex,nofollow" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body {
        margin:      '... (length=2131)
null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quite easily using their native Facebook PHP-SDK:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

Here's the API method documentation for sending notifications: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/notifications

Example usage with PHP-SDK:

```
/* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'POST',
  '/{user-id}/notifications',
  array (
    'href' => '/testurl?param1=value1',
    'template' => 'This is a test message',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

Comment: The Reason i don't want to use the SDK is can't get to work at all. I even asked a question about it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219564/how-to-use-facebook-sdk-4-0-without-composer-with-autoloader

Comment: Got the SDK to work, but this now throws an error that '$session' is undefined.

Comment: Are you creating a facebook app session prior to making this api call? Take a look at this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0